# '6/1/2012' < '6/1/2012 0:00:00.000' = true?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run this code in SQL-Server 2008,

```
select case when '6/1/2012' < '6/1/2012' then 1 else 0 end
```

I get 0.

And if I run,

```
select case when '6/1/2012 0:00:00.000' < '6/1/2012' then 1 else 0 end
```

I also get 0.

**BUT**, if I run

```
select case when '6/1/2012' < '6/1/2012 0:00:00.000' then 1 else 0 end
```

I get 1.

Why is this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My guess is:

1. You're comparing two strings (nothing in your query indicates that they are supposed to be compared as dates).
2. If two strings are equal except for extra characters in one, the longer string is "greater".

You may be expecting your database to automatically detect dates, but that would involve parsing **every** string you give it in case it's a date, which would hurt performance and could also be confusing (if something gets converted to a date and you didn't mean for it to be).

Answer (score 6):

You have to cast them as `datetime` to compare them as `datetime` values.  This returns `0`:

```
select case when cast('6/1/2012' as datetime) < cast('6/1/2012 0:00:00.000' as datetime) then 1 else 0 end
```